# How can I rename or alias an lpr CUPS queue name?

Tags: printing, cups-lpd, lpd

I plugged a printer into Ubuntu and it was instantly configured. **Amazing!**

Now I want to share that printer on the network, so I've told CUPS to do that and I can print to the printer using ipp://10.67.5.3/printers/HP-Laserjet-p3005. So I know it works.

Also I've set up xinetd and cups-lpd (part of the cups-bsd package) to be able to print to it using lpd.

However I have 20 machines on this network all set up to print to lpd://10.67.5.3/lp1 which is the address of the previous print server. I'd like to tell the Ubuntu machine to use lp1 as the lpr queue name for HP-Laserjet-p3005 as this would mean I don't have to reconfigure 20 machines.

Is this possible (it must be!)? Either renaming the queue (which was auto-generated) or providing an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I could not see the wood for the trees. I deleted the auto-set-up queue and created a new one with the name I wanted.

Comment: That is actually the easiest way without going looking for the print queue configuration file.  hplip and indeed cups both ask for a name when you setup a new printer so its easy to create it how you want it then test before removing the old queue. I will say though, hplip is far better at setting up its own printers than cups, no need to search just select the found printer and begin the minimal config needed.